# PyObjC - streaming music with NSSound

Tags: python, pyobjc

I tried to make a simple music streaming app using Python+PyObjC following [this blog](http://patternbuffer.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/play-mp3-from-python-on-mac/)

```
import Foundation
from AppKit import NSSound
sound = NSSound.alloc()
url = Foundation.NSURL.URLWithString_("http://206.217.213.235:8050/")
sound.initWithContentsOfURL_byReference_(url, True)

sound.play()
```

And it fails

```
>>> sound.play()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: cannot access attribute 'play' of NIL 'NSSound' object
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the NSSound object in AppKit provides a way to **play** AIFF and WAV sound **files** in Mac applications and not Shoutcast **streams**. See: http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/PyObjC

I quickly tried to find an existing Python module to do what you want, but it seems none exist. There are however plenty of apps, implemented in Python that do this, that you could analyse to figure out how they do it. For example: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DeeFuzzer

The best alternative I could find for you was [How do I capture an mp3 stream with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187552/how-do-i-capture-an-mp3-stream-with-python) that talks about **capturing** a stream for local playback.

Answer (score 1):

to add to @William Denman's answer `initWithContentsOfURL_byReference_` is returning nil, which means an error happened creating the sound. in this case we know its because the URL should point to a valid file that `NSSound` understands (AIFF, WAVE, NeXT, SD2, AU, and MP3).

even if `NSSound` worked in this instance, it would have to download the entire file before playback; as @William Denman pointed out this doesn't work with streams.